# ¿Arrojar string dependiendo de 4 valores de 4 variables?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función en JavaScript que obtiene el tiempo en días, horas, minutos y segundos de un campo de una base de datos, el cual está almacenado en segundos.
Este es el código de la función:

```js
function licencesTime(seconds){
    var numdays = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
    var numhours = Math.floor((seconds % 86400) / 3600);
    var numminutes = Math.floor(((seconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    var numseconds = ((seconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60;

    if (numdays == 0 && numhours == 0 && numminutes == 0 && numseconds == 0){
        return "Vencida";
    } else if (numseconds == 0){
        return numdays + " dias " + numhours + " horas " + numminutes + " minutos ";
    } else {
        return numdays + " dias " + numhours + " horas " + numminutes + " minutos " + numseconds + " segundos";
    }
}
```

Como se ve, hago una comprobación para ver si no están todos los campos en cero, luego para ver los segundos, pero mi intención es comprobar cada campo, y dependiendo de esos valores, no mostrar los que estén = 0, ¿existe algún método más fácil o debo hacer una comprobación por cada variable? Pues eso me llevaría muchas líneas... Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La única manera que veo de reducir los if es utilizar el operador ternario:

```
if (numdays == 0 && numhours == 0 && numminutes == 0 && numseconds == 0){
        return "Vencida";
} else {

    const snumdays = numdays === 0 ? '' : numdays + ' dias ';
    const snumhours = numhours === 0 ? '' : numhours + ' horas ';
    const snumminutes = numminutes  === 0 ? '' : numminutes  + ' minutos ';
    const snumseconds = numseconds  === 0 ? '' : numseconds  + ' segundos';

    return snumdays + snumhours + snumminutes + snumseconds;
}
```

O si gustas, al final podrías utilizar string interpolation:

```
return `${snumdays} ${snumhours} ${snumminutes} ${snumseconds}`;
```

Ojalá te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: a pesar que respondi lo mismo pero resumido xD me gusta mas tu respuesta!

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Carlos, me ha funcionado igual que la línea de sioesi, ahora mismo me pongo a estudiar el operador ternario, nunca había escuchado de el.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias ocupar operaciones ternarias

```
return numdays !== 0 ? numdays + " dias " : "" + numhours !== 0 ? numhours + " horas " : "" + numminutes !== 0 ? numminutes + " minutos " : "" + numseconds !== 0 ? numseconds + " segundos " : ""
```

Solo para aclararte, el operador ternario es un "if lineal" lo que hago es decir

SI `numdays` es DISTINTO de 0, escribe `numdays + " dias "` el equivalente a:

```
if (numdays !== 0) {
    return numdays + " dias";
} else {
    //no devuelve nada
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero me es difícil entender el operador de este modo, pues no quiero añadir algo sin entender como funciona jaja, me funcionó. Pero me quedo con la de Carlos Pozos porque la puedo estudiar mejor.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMarrufo edite mi respuesta para que vayas entendiendo esta operacion, saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

Si te molestaban los if's esta solución no tiene ninguno:

```js
function licencesTime(seconds) {

  var numdays = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
  var numhours = 0;//<-- ejemplo siendo 0
  var numminutes = Math.floor(((seconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
  var numseconds = 0;//<-- ejemplo siendo 0

  return (!(numdays + numhours + numminutes + numseconds)) ? "Vencida" :
    ((numdays) ? numdays + " dias " : "") +
    ((numhours) ? numhours + " horas " : "") +
    ((numminutes) ? numminutes + " minutos " : "") +
    ((numseconds) ? numseconds + " segundos" : "");

}

console.log(licencesTime(1567115207067));
```

En realidad tiene operadores ternarios anidados, y la primera condicion, en lugar de evaluar cada valor, evaluamos que la suma de todo sea 0, porque 0*n es siempre 0. Como 0 lo coercionamos a booleano, queda false, al negarlo con ! queda true, y en ese caso es "Vencida".